# Set Appointment using iPhone SDK

Tags: objective-c, iphone, cocoa-touch

I know you can access the Contact Store from the SDk, but is it possible to create and read appointment data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is currently not accessable through the 2.x SDK.

If this is something you need you should go to http://bugreport.apple.com/ and signin with your developer account and write a feature request. It will most likely be marked as a duplicate but Apple tracks duplicates and the more requests for something the higher it moves on their radar.

Comment: this was from 2008, is not possible to create and read appointments in iPhone from code yet?